# Doubt about \pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, foreach, loops

I was using tikz and I had a problem using `\draw[]` inside a `\foreach` loop, so I found `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and I have doubts about how it works. This is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
        xmin= -2, xmax=2,
        ymin=-8, ymax=8,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel=$y$,
        width=\linewidth
        ]
        \addplot[line width=1.5pt ,samples=100, Purple] {x^3};
        \addplot[no markers, Green, thick] {-5};
        
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1.5, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5}{%
            \draw[dashed] (#1,0) -- (#1,-5);
        }
        
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1.5, -1, -0.5}{%, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ArrowLength}{abs(#1)*0.1} 
            \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (#1,-5) -- ({#1 + \ArrowLength}); 
            \node at (#1,-5) {\ArrowLength};
            }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this example I want an increasing length for the arrows, but I get arrows with appareantly the same length. I think that this is not working because I'm adding `#1 + \ArrowLength`

I'd like to get something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
        xmin= -2, xmax=2,
        ymin=-8, ymax=8,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel=$y$,
        width=\linewidth
        ]
        \addplot[line width=1.5pt ,samples=100, Purple] {x^3};
        \addplot[no markers, Green, thick] {-5};
        
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1.5, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5}{%
            \draw[dashed] (#1,0) -- (#1,-5);
        }
        
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (-1.5, -5) -- (-1.1,-5);
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (-1, -5) -- (-0.73,-5);
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (-0.5, -5) -- (-0.37,-5);
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (1.5, -5) -- (1.91,-5);
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (1, -5) -- (1.27,-5);
        \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (0.5, -5) -- (0.64,-5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've just found `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` so I don't know how exactly it works. Please, explain to me a little why it's beahaving like that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point `({#1 + \ArrowLength})` was missing an y coordinate.

The code inside `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` works if `#1` is used directly instead of defining `\ArrowLength` which is replaced by `abs(#1)*0.27`. For the text in the `\node`, `\fpeval` is used to evaluate this expression. Also the option `below` is added.

Both `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` are combined in one instance.

The code `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}` and `\usepackage{tikz}` are unnecessary in this example and were removed. The code `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` is removed and instead, `dvipsnames` is given as an option to `\documentclass`.

After `\begin{axis}[` and after `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` no `%` is necessary.

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}%not necessary from 2022-06-01: see https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
    xmin=-2, xmax=2,
    ymin=-8, ymax=8,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    width=\linewidth
  ]
    \addplot[line width=1.5pt, samples=100, Purple] {x^3};
    \addplot[no markers, Green, thick] {-5};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1.5, -1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5}{
      \draw[dashed] (#1,0) -- (#1,-5);
      \draw[-stealth, red!50!black, line width=1.5pt] (#1,-5) -- ({#1 + abs(#1)*0.27},-5);
      \node[below] at (#1,-5) {\fpeval{abs(#1)*0.27}};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]